# Can i add conditional events on svelte components?

Tags: events, svelte

is it possible for an event to be fired on a condition defined in the parent component ?

I have an input component where i want to capture the input.. sometimes, but most of the time i dont want the event to fire

```
   //App.html
   <Input on:inputData="doStuff(event)" fireEvent=true />    

   //Input.html
   <input bind:value=value (fireEvent ? on:keyup='fire("inputData", { value })' : false )/>
```

What happens currently is that `fireEvent` is ignored and `on:keyup` allways fires

**UPDATE**
I changed the keyup into a function call where i checked the parameter before firing the event, it works but its kinda wacky

```
//App.html
<Input on:inputData='doStuff(event.value)' fireEvent={true} />
 ...
  methods: {
  doStuff(text) {
    console.log('here is the stuff', text);
  }

//Input.html
<input bind:value=value on:keyup='setData({ value })'/>
...
methods: {
  setData(text) {
    if(this.get().fireEvent) {
      this.fire("inputData", text)
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone got a prettier solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont know why i didnt think of this but this is excatly what `onupdate` is for

```
//App.html
<Input on:inputData='doStuff(event.value)' fireEvent={true} />
     ...
methods: {
 doStuff(text) {
   console.log('here is the stuff', text);
 }

//Input.html
<input bind:value=value />
...
onupdate({ changed, current, previous }) {
  if(this.get().fireEvent) {
    this.fire("inputData", current)
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Very late to the party, but I had a similar problem and ended up solving it with an action. For mine, I needed to attach a click listener to a button only if a certain condition was truthy. A more generic example could be:

```
<button use:conditionalEvent({condition: foo, event: 'click', callback: bar})>...</button>

...

function conditionalEvent(node, {condition, event, callback}) {
    if (condition) {
        node.addEventListener(event, callback);
    }

    return {
        destroy() {
            node.removeEventListener(event, callback)
        } 
    }
}
```

The markup could be less verbose if it was only for a single callback or event type, but you get the point.
If the condition can change with user input, you can also return an update function:

```
function changingCondition(node, {condition, event, callback}) {
    function update(condition) {
        if (condition) {
            node.addEventListener(event, callback);
        } else {
            node.removeEventListener(event, callback);
        }
    }

    update(condition);

    return {
        update,
        destroy() {
            node.removeEventListener(event, callback)
        } 
    }
}
```

And the update will run whenever `condition` changes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it worked. note the lower case 'fireevent'. The capital letter threw it off. Naturally you'd have to change it to on:inputData etc.

```js
 methods: {
     test(evt) {
  console.log('evt.fireEvent', evt.target.getAttributeNode("fireEvent").value);
  if (evt.target.getAttributeNode("fireevent").value && evt.target.getAttributeNode("fireevent").value=="true")
      console.log('do the happy dance');
  else
      console.log('do NOTHING');

     }
 }
```

```html
<button on:click="test(event)" fireevent="false">Test</button>
```

Comment: yeah i had already attempted this with a method like this and it works but i dont like how it looks.. also i realized that my problem is solved by onupdate